# How can you drop certain dates in a data frame grouped by day?

Tags: python, dataframe, error-handling, group-by, drop

I am working on a code that groupes a data frame by date:

```
gk = df_HR.groupby(['date'])
```

I now get a data frame where every first row from each date is looking like this:

```
2022-05-23  22:18   60  2022-05-23 22:18:00 1653344280  1.000000
2022-05-24  00:00   54  2022-05-24 00:00:00 1653350400  0.900000

....
```

I want to drop as an example all the data for the date '2022-05-24'. However, when I use the .drop() function I get the error 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'drop''.
How can I still drop all the data from this date?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data as well as expected results?

Answer (score 0):

From what i gather, the goal is to group the data frames by date, and drop dataframes with date's on a certain day

```py
import pandas as pd

# ...

gk = df_HR.groupby(['date'])
good_dfs = []
for date, sub_df in gk:
  if DATE_TO_DROP not in date:
    good_dfs.append(sub_df)

final_df = pd.concat(good_dfs)
```

Alternatively, you can just drop rows where 'date' has that string included

```py
df_HR.drop(df_HR[ DATE_TO_REMOVE in df_HR.date].index, inplace=True)
```

The above is for removing a single date. if you have multiple dates here are those two options again

option1:

```py
dates_to_drop = [] 
gk = df_HR.groupby(['date'])
good_dfs = []
for date, sub_df in gk:
  for bad_date in dates_to_drop:
    if bad_date in date:
      good_dfs.append(sub_df)

final_df = pd.concat(good_dfs)
```

option2:

```py
dates_to_drop = [] 
for bad_date in dates_to_drop:
  df_HR.drop(df_HR[ bad_date in df_HR.date ].index, inplace=True)
```

The reason we have to loop through is because the dates in the DF include more than just the string you're looking for. checking for substring existence in python involves using the 'in' operator. But we can't check if a list of strings is in a string, and so we loop over bad dates, removing all rows with each bad date.

Comment: do I have to replace DATE_TO_REMOVE with as an example '2022-05-23'? Because for your first solution it works, but I need to remove multiple dates and the second one gives the error when I replace DATE_TO_REMOVE with as an example '2022-05-23'.

Comment: That helps a lot. However, now that only the good dates are in the data frame, I want to compare every last value from each row (1.000000 & 0.900000) in my example data frame, to a daily average that was calculated in another dataframe. Right now it does not connect this daily average to all the values in the df_final data frame from the same day. How can this be solved?

Comment: | 62 2022-05-24 00:00 54 2022-05-24 00:00:00 1653350400 0.900000 |
| 63 2022-05-24 00:01 54 2022-05-24 00:01:00 1653350460 0.900000 |

Above is the first data frame, down is the second data frame

| 0 2022-05-24 1653338880 2022-05-23 20:48:00 1653361560 2022-05-24 03:06:00 1653365160 57 0.950000
1 2022-05-25 1653427500 2022-05-24 21:25:00 1653455520 2022-05-25 05:12:00 1653459120 60 1.000000

Comment: use the same logic from option2. make a list of dates you're comparing. then, for each date, get rows from each df that have that datestring in it's 'date' col. in the for loop where you get rows, you can then compare for that date and store it in something

Answer (score 0):

Save your group by result in Dataframe-df and then use below code to select list of dates you want to drop .

```
date_list_filter = [datetime(2009, 5, 2),
             datetime(2010, 8, 22)]

df.drop(date_list, inplace=True)
```

hope this helps !

Comment: I copied your code in the following way:  
`df = df_HR.groupby(['date'])  

date_list_filter = [datetime(2022, 5, 23),  
             datetime(2022, 5, 24)]  

df.drop(date_list, inplace=True)`

Still it gives the error: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'drop'

Comment: You need to drop date before group By operations but in case you want to drop after group by need to use mean , agg functions and then try drop .

Answer (score 0):

See below code to explain further

```
my_date=[datetime(2009, 5, 2),
    datetime(2010, 8, 22),
     datetime(2022,8,22),
     datetime(2009,5,2),
     datetime(2010,8,22)       
    ]

df=pd.DataFrame(my_date)
df.columns=['Date']
df1=df.groupby('Date').mean()
df1 # now see below data of dataframe df1
```

[image]

```
df1.drop('2009-05-02',inplace=True) 
# given date will be dropped-see screenshot  
df1
```

[image]